# Python recursive function giving different error or correct output

Tags: python, recursion

I am writing a program that works out the ratios of different recipes for the game Factorio (as lazy as this seems). For it, I am using the below code that recursively works out each ratio for each item.

```
"""Imports"""
from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict

# Item is a named tuple called Item which expects two attributes, craft time and ingredients

Item = namedtuple('Item', ['craft_time', 'ingredients'])

# A dictionary of all the different items to be crafted

items = {'iron gear wheel': Item(craft_time=0.5, ingredients={None}),
         'copper cable': Item(craft_time=0.5, ingredients={None}),
         'transport belt': Item(craft_time=0.5, ingredients={'iron gear wheel': 1}),
         'fast transport belt': Item(craft_time=0.5, ingredients={'iron gear wheel': 5, 'transport belt': 1})}


# Functions

def find_ratio(item, rate_of_production):
    """
    This recursive function finds the ratio of factories needed to produce the item at the rate of production.
    """

    # creates a default dict object
    dict_of_ratios = defaultdict(list)

    # adds the ratio of the item itself to the dict of ratios
    dict_of_ratios[item].append(rate_of_production / items[item][0])

    # iterate through the rest of the ingredients of the item
    for ingredient in iter(items[item][1]):

        # if there are no ingredients
        if ingredient is None:
            break

        # iterate through the returned dict from find ratio and add them to the currently running dict of ratios
        print(item)
        for item, ratio in iter(find_ratio(ingredient, items[item][1]    [ingredient] * rate_of_production).items()):
            dict_of_ratios[item].append(ratio)

# iterate through dict of ratios and sum all of the values
for item in iter(dict_of_ratios.keys()):
    dict_of_ratios[item] = sum(dict_of_ratios[item])

    return dict_of_ratios


found_ratio = find_ratio("fast transport belt", 2)

# print the resulting ratio
print('You will need:')
for i in found_ratio:
    print("\t{} {} factories".format(found_ratio[i], i))
```

However, sometimes when I run this program I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
fast transport belt
  File "E:/Will/William's Projects/Code/Tests/FactrioRatios.py", line 52, in <module>
iron gear wheel
found_ratio = find_ratio("fast transport belt", 2)
  File "E:/Will/William's Projects/Code/Tests/FactrioRatios.py", line 41, in    find_ratio
for item, ratio in iter(find_ratio(ingredient, items[item][1][ingredient] * 
rate_of_production).items()):
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

And other times the expected result:

```
You will need:
    4.0 fast transport belt factories
    4.0 transport belt factories
    8.0 iron gear wheel factories
```

Why is this and how can I fix this?

Comment: `ingredients={None}` is a `set` containing just one element, `None`. Did you want to create an empty dict? Use `ingredients={}`.

Comment: Thanks! Code works fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments you will need to remove the `set` containing `None`:

```
ingredients={None}
```

and likely change it to an empty `dict`:

```
ingredients={}
```

Also you will need to do something reasonable when you access the empty dict, maybe:

```
items[item][1].get(ingredient, 0)
```